# How can I hide the absolutely enormous top bar in editors/apps such as eclipse and visual studio code?

Tags: 22.10

[The enormous top bar I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW18d.png)

This bar appears whenever I use an app such as eclipse, visual studio code etc etc, and I don't want it to be there because it confiscates a bunch of the area I'm supposed to see. I tried hiding it through the app but there is no such option. I am pretty sure this is ubuntu-related (and it might just be displaying the title).

If there is an option to make it smaller (at least) I could also use that.
Sorry if this is a bad question, I'm quite new to Ubuntu (as you might've noticed already) and this forum.

My Ubuntu version is 22.10 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F11 is the (commonly used) function key to go full screen.

[image: VSCode before pressing F11]

[image: VSCode after pressing F11]

Comment: Hey! I had an idea to use F11 to go full screen. Visual Studio Code works with this but eclipse has something else bound to F11. Is there another way to activate fullscreen? Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. Thank you sir, I wish you a great day